# npm error code EINVALIDTAGNAME when trying to install protobufjs

Tags: javascript, npm

I got an error when installing protobufjs with this command:

```
npm install protobufjs [--save --save-prefix=~]
```

the error is:

```
npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME
npm ERR! Invalid tag name "[--save": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: The problem has to do with npm and not protobuf, so I removed the protobuf tag. I fixed the formatting of the command and the error and also added some more context to the error.

Comment: try `npm install protobufjs --save`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where did you find that syntax?

Square brackets in the instructions for how to run something generally mean that the part in square brackets is optional. i.e. that you can run the command with or without the part in square brackets.

For npm you can run:

```
npm install protobufjs
```

or

```
npm install protobufjs --save-prod
```

or

```
npm install protobufjs --save-dev
```

etc., depending on what you're trying to do.

I believe older versions of npm used `--save` instead of `--save-prod` and in later versions of npm, `--save-prod` is the default.

```
$ npm --version
6.4.1
$ npm install protobufjs
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.

+ protobufjs@6.8.8
added 14 packages from 35 contributors and audited 16 packages in 4.502s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Comment: i found in https://www.npmjs.com/package/protobufjs sir thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Just simply use the following **Syntax** `#nodejs` `#Express`

```
 npm install protobufjs
```

**Insted of :**

```
 npm install protobufjs --save-prod
```

or

```
 npm install protobufjs --save
```

Because the newer version of `Nodejs` by default having `--save` method

Answer (score -1):

As best answer says:

```
prefix=~]
```

that's the problm

in my case was just a + for this line:

```
npm install --save request request-promise cheerio puppeteer+
```

copy-pasting from website, make me do this mistake

hope it works